# Whitelabel Page Error on "localhost:5050/error" route

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin

Earlier I was getting whitelabel error when i visit "localhost:5050" and after looking at error I created a custom error page for '/error' route because in the error i see that there is no explicit mapping for '/error'.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class ErrorHandler {

    @GetMapping(value=["/error"])
    fun ShowError
        (
        request: HttpServletRequest?,
        response: HttpServletResponse?
    ) :String{
       return "Custom error page"
    }
}
```

But whenever i go to "localhost:5050/error" I am getting this error the same whitelabel page error but with different status code.

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Nov 19 19:03:11 IST 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).

Status code for "localhost:5050/error" is 999 and for "localhost:5050" it was 404. I do not know why it is different for both the cases.

1. I have already put my controller class next to my main application function.
2. I also tried to resolve this error by creating route for "/" but getting same error.

Please help me in figuring out my mistake.

Comment: Can you please share main class?

Comment: class SpeechServiceApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpeechServiceApplication>(*args)
}

Comment: Are you using @SpringBootApplication annotation?

Comment: You have used @RestController, it does not use HTML based response because `@ResponseBody` is configured by `@RestController`.

Comment: create a minimal github project because we can not see what is problem. :)